# Slow anonymous function

Tags: matlab, performance, anonymous-function

Suppose you have a loop with 50000 iterations and want to calculate mean values (scalars) from alot of matrices. This is not complete, but roughly like this:

```
for k=1:50000
...
mean=sum(sum(matrix))/numel(matrix); %Arithmetic mean
...
end
```

And now want to include different mean equations to choose from. First I tried this:

```
average='arithmetic'
for k=1:50000
...
switch average
    case 'arithmetic'
        mean=sum(sum(matrix))/numel(matrix); %Arithmetic mean
    case 'geometric'
        mean=prod(prod(matrix)).^(1/numel(matrix)); %Geometric mean
    case 'harmonic'
        mean=numel(matrix)/sum(sum(1./matrix)); %Harmonic mean
end
...
end
```

This is obviously alot slower than the first loop because it needs to find the matching string for every iteration which feels really unnecessary. Then I tried this:

```
average='arithmetic'
switch average
    case 'arithmetic'
        eq=@(arg)sum(sum(arg))/numel(arg); %Arithmetic mean
    case 'geometric'
        eq=@(arg)prod(prod(arg)).^(1/numel(arg)); %Geometric mean
    case 'harmonic'
        eq=@(arg)numel(arg)/sum(sum(1./arg)); %Harmonic mean
end

for k=1:50000
...
mean=eq(matrix); %Call mean equation
...
end
```

This is still about twice as slow as the first loop and I don't get why. The two last loops are almost similar in speed.

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I achieve the same performance as the first loop with this extra feature?

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Having the switch inside the loop is performing a comparison 50000 times which only needs to be performed once, something I'd advise against.

The second is a little more subtle, but it's quite probable the eq function is being dynamically looked up every iteration and possibly interpreted each time as well (not sure how MATLAB does optimisation). Your best bet for performance is probably to put the for loop inside of the switch

```
switch average
    case 'arithmetic'
        for ... end
    case 'geometric'
        for ... end
    case 'harmonic'
        for ... end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, every function, even [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html), can be expected to have some amount of extra overhead involved in calling it, making them slightly slower than their single-line expression counterparts in your example. However, in this case there *may* be extra overhead due to the fact that functions by the name `eq` already exist in abundance in MATLAB, since [`eq` is the method name of the overloaded `==` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eq.html). Using the [WHICH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) command like so:

```
>> which eq -all
```

Will show you that `eq` is *heavily* overloaded, with one existing for each of the fundamental data types and most objects.

I would try using a different name for your anonymous function handle just to see if dispatching *may* be a factor, although I kinda doubt it based on the [function precedence order](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-58170.html#bresuvu-3) (i.e. variables always appear to take precedence). Your best solution performance-wise may be to avoid the extra function call overhead by doing something like what [DavW suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679028/slow-anonymous-function/5679107#5679107).

I would like to make one other suggestion. Many of the mathematical operations you are doing can be greatly improved to make them more efficient, specifically by making use of the function [MEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html) and the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) to reshape an entire matrix into a column vector:

```
result = mean(matrix(:));  %# For the arithmetic mean

result = prod(matrix(:))^(1/numel(matrix));  %# For the geometric mean

result = 1/mean(1./matrix(:));  %# For the harmonic mean
```

Note that I didn't use the name `mean` for my variable since that is already used for the [built-in function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html), and you definitely **don't** want to shadow it.

Comment: Or `exp(mean(log(matrix(:))))` for the geometric mean.  Or even the builtin functions from the stats toolbox, http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/geomean.html http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/harmmean.html

Comment: Yes thanks, another variable name helped a lot, can't believe I overlooked that. 
And thanks for the advice on the mathematical operations. But I have matrices with multiple layers. And I want to have a mean for every layer. This gives me a total mean. Is there a way to accomplish this too?

Comment: @shant: If you are dealing with, say, 3-D matrices, you could use the additional dimension arguments to functions like MEAN and PROD. For example, the arithmetic mean would be `mean(mean(matrix,1),2)`, which would give you a mean value for every layer in the third dimension. In the same vein, the geometric mean would be `prod(prod(matrix,1),2).^(1/(size(matrix,1)*size(matrix,2)))` and the harmonic mean would be `1./mean(mean(1./matrix,1),2)`. So, did using a name other than `eq` for your anonymous functions actually speed things up?

Comment: Yes it did actually, not as fast as my first loop, but still much better than before, thanks. As for the mean equations I think I have to stick to what I wrote originally (but I don't use numel for 3D). I tried the mean function like that but it was actually slower than spelling out the definition.